# Alpha-channel all 1.0 in WebGLRenderTarget when reading rendered image for post-processing

Tags: glsl, webgl, three.js, texture2d

I am using Three.js to render the world to a WebGLRenderTarget. My world does not full the whole screen and thus, has transparent background. The purpose is to provide alpha-channel aware image effects.

1. I render the world to a WebGLRenderTarget buffer
2. I try to post-process this by reading from the buffer and writing to the real screen

My post-processing function depends on the alpha channel. However, looks like that somehow Three.JS post-processing shader fails to read the alpha channel correctly - it is all 1.0 no matter what values I try to put in to WebGLRenderTarget.

The simple way to demostrate the problem.

I create a render target:

```
        var rtParameters = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat};

        for(var i=0; i<this.bufferCount; i++) {
            this.buffers[i] = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.width, this.height, rtParameters);
        }
```

I clear the buffer setting alpha to 0.3::

```
        function clear(buf) {
            // For debugging purposes we set clear color alpha
            renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xff00ff), 0.3);
            renderer.clearTarget(buf, true, true, true);
        }

        // Clean up both buffers for the start
        clear(buffers[0]);
```

And then I use this buffer as a read buffer and render to the screen in my post-processing fragment shader function (ThreeJS post-processing examples):

```
            "void main() {",

                    // texture is the buffer I rendered before
                    "vec4 sample = texture2D( texture, vUv);",

                    // Everything goes to white (1.0) when trying to visualize the
                    // alpha channel of previously rendered WebGLTarget.
                    // It should get value 0.3 - slight gray
                    "gl_FragColor = vec4(sample.a, sample.a, sample.a, 1.0);",
            "}"
```

Other color values are read correctly. If I use `vec4(sample.r, sample.g, sample.b, 1.0)` it directly copies as expected.

- Is there a problem of clearing the alpha channel for WebGLRenderTarget?
- Is there a problem of reading alpha values as having WebGLRenderTarget as texture for 2D image post-processing in GLSL shader?

Comment: You need to also share how you're initialising the WebGLRenderTarget.

Comment: Added the init code. (Note: tested THREE.RGBFormat and THREE.RGBAFormat and there doesn't seem to be different in the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that implements what I believe you are trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/6vK6W/3/

Comment: Looks good... diving it now and see if something is different

Comment: Thanks. With following your example and tearing my code apart piece by piece I was finally able to find the culprint. I blitted out the final image to DOM using <canvas> 2d context drawImage() and it was destroying the alpha channel out of it. So one should not mix 2d and 3d context data if one wants to preserve alpha channel.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa `drawImage` “destroys” the alpha channel because it's doing compositing. You could (1) use `putImageData` instead, which is specified not to composite (but this requires having an ImageData object so is probably not applicable), (2) clear the canvas to transparent (not white) before drawing onto it, or (3) set the `globalCompositeOperation` to `copy` instead of the default `source-over`.

Comment: In fact I was clearing canvas to transparent, but looks like it was still no go. The reason why I was using drawImage() is that I had to scale down the orignal photo image which were too big to fit into texture dimensiosn (several megapixels).

Comment: I figured out this by running <canvas> drawImage() and no <canvas> pure WebGL renderings side by side and the latter was working fine.